# tmap view mode covers half screen

Tags: r, tmap

Why tmap view mode only covers half of my screen? is there an argument for that?

```
library(tmap)

data(World)

tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons(c("HPI", "economy")) +
  tm_facets(ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code using `dput`?

Comment: updated the plot with examples.

Comment: Perhaps `tm_facets(nrow = 2)` ?

Comment: that's not the question though.